# include nested relation with ASC or DESC order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im returning a model like this for JSON request

```
 def index
    @categories = Category.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @categories.to_json(:include => :todos) }
  end
end
```

now when i return this @categories, i want to include :todos with Ascending order of and attribute say "positon". Is there a way i can do that..?

something like this

```
    render json: @categories.to_json(:include => :todos, :order=>"postion, ASC")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an association like this in your category.rb:

```
has_many :ordered_todos,
             :class_name => "ToDo",
             :order      => "position ASC"
```

Then just write:

```
render json: @categories.to_json(:include => :ordered_todos)
```

Answer (score 1):

user1541507 has a good answer.

If you find you don't want to use the has_many approach to order, and you want to add computed attributes, consider using [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) and creating views to display json.  Here's [the railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder) that explains it well.

Comment: thanks for the share.. After this reading this i figured out that jbuilder is the one which i need for some of my other purposes..  You made my work simple... thanks a lot..